# Is there a way to be able to use a variable path using os

Tags: python

The goal is to run through a half stable and half variable path.

I am trying to run through a path (go to lowest folder which is called Archive) and fill a list with files that have a certain ending. This works quite well for a stable path such as this.

fileInPath='\\server123456789\provider\COUNTRY\CATEGORY\Archive

My code runs through the path (recursive) and lists all files that have a certain ending. This works well. For simplicity I will just print the file name in the following code.

```
import csv
import os

fileInPath='\\\\server123456789\\provider\\COUNTRY\\CATEGORY\\Archive
fileOutPath=some path

csvSeparator=';'

fileList = []

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(fileInPath):
 for file in files:

    if file[-3:].upper()=='PAR':
        print (file)
```

The problem is that I can manage to have country and category to be variable e.g. by using *

Comment: you are missing a `'`

Comment: Check out the `glob` module https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html or `pathlib` https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Answer (score 1):

The standard library module [pathlib](http://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) provides a simple way to do this.

Your file list can be obtained with

```
from pathlib import Path

list(Path("//server123456789/provider/".glob("*/*/Archive/*.PAR"))
```

Note I'm using `/` instead of `\\` `pathlib` handles the conversion for you on windows.

Comment: Thanks. I already tried using pathlib. But for some reason it will not be installed/imported at all. Is there a way I can have the flexbility using os maybe even without building the path every time and checking if the current directory is an Archive older? I thought about this but there must (probably?) be a way using  a one-liner like you but just with os instead? I couldn't figure something out yet

Comment: `pathlib` was introduced with Python 3.4. The other option is to use the `glob` module, it provides the same functionality as the `Path.glob` method.